# Argument names using r-autoyas

Tags: r, emacs, ess, yasnippet

I've recently been using r-autoyas (0.28) when working in R scripts (emacs 24.3.1, ESS 13.09-1, Windows 8.1) and have found it really helpful. It works out-of-box on loaded R libraries and user-defined functions after setting `(setq r-autoyas-expand-package-functions-only nil)`.

However, I would like to tweak one small aspect of it: I would like to keep the argument names when explicitly entering their values. For instance, if I type 'rnorm' and then TAB to expand the snippet, I get:

```
rnorm(n= , mean=0, sd=1)
```

and type 10 TAB 100 TAB and then TAB again to leave `sd=1` as default. What I end with is:

```
rnorm(10, 100)
```

and what I'd like to have is:

```
rnorm(n=10, mean=100)
```

which makes for code that I prefer. I know older versions of `r-autoyas` used to do this, since it shows up in the tutorial video on youtube, where he uses `C-d` to skip an argument, and TAB to cycle throw them. Further, if an argument is skipped (say `mean`), then all subsequent arguments are named. So for example if I instead typed 10 TAB TAB 50 `C-g` I get:

```
rnorm(10, sd=50)
```

Basically I'm wondering if it's possible to turn on leaving the argument name for all arguments, not just ones that follow a skipped argument. I can't seem to find anything on the github site which shows how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `r-autoyas-remove-explicit-assignments` to `nil`.
You can customize this variable `M-x customize-option r-autoyas-remove-explicit-assignments`. There, you also find a description of this variable.

Comment: Hi Tobias, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I saws that in the help but somehow didn't make the connection it would do what I wanted. Thanks!